# Creating unique user names by joining first name and several characters on last name

Tags: vba, excel

Im writing a macro to creating a Unique user names by joining First Name and first letters from the Last Name depending on the uniqueness of the user name.

For example:

There are 3 First Names:

1. ABCD, 2.ABCD, 3.ABCD

And there are 3 Last Names:

1. QWER, 2.QWER, 3.QWER.

User Names should be:

1. ABCDQ@somewhere.com, 2.ABCDQW@somewhere.com , 3.ABCDQWE@somewhere.com.

To get this I wrote following code on VBA,

```
Sub Create_User_Name()
Dim fName As String
Dim lName As String
Dim uName As String
Dim eMail As String

Dim preFname As String
Dim preLname As String
Dim preUname As String

Dim fNameCol As Integer
Dim fNameRow As Integer

Dim lNameCol As Integer
Dim lNameRow As Integer

Dim rowNumber As Integer

Dim leftVal As Integer

'For loop starting here to increment row number

For rowNumber = 2 To 7802

fNameCol = 1
fNameRow = rowNumber

lNameCol = 2
lNameRow = rowNumber

fName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(fNameRow, fNameCol)
lName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lNameRow, lNameCol)


preFname = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(fNameRow - 1, fNameCol)
preLname = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lNameRow - 1, lNameCol)

eMail = "" & "somewhere.com"

leftVal = 1
uName = fName + Left(lName, leftVal) + "@" + eMail
preUname = preFname + Left(preLname, leftVal) + "@" + eMail

If UCase(uName) = UCase(preUname) Then
Do While uName = preUname

uName = fName + Left(lName, leftVal) + "@" + eMail
preUname = preFname + Left(preLname, leftVal) + "@" + eMail

leftVal = leftVal + 1
rowNumber = rowNumber + 1

Loop

uName = fName + Left(lName, leftVal) + "@" + eMail
preUname = preFname + Left(preLname, leftVal) + "@" + eMail

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNumber, 3).Value = uName

 Else
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNumber, 3).Value = uName
 End If

Next rowNumber

End Sub
```

It's not working as I intend. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: "It's not working as I intend" is a generic issue description which is true for any problem. Please be more specific: Tell us what you pretend your code should do and **what it actually does**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a bad effort. I have changed your code and have tested that it works. Have commented pretty heavily.

You should also add a check to see if the name is blank and if so dont output any name.

```
Sub Create_User_Name()
Dim fName As String
Dim lName As String
Dim uName As String
Dim eMail As String

Dim preUname As String

Dim fNameCol As Long
Dim fNameRow As Long

Dim lNameCol As Long
Dim lNameRow As Long

Dim rowNumber As Long

Dim leftVal As Long

'For loop starting here to increment row number

    For rowNumber = 2 To 7802

        'Gets Column Data
        fName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNumber, 1)
        lName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNumber, 2)

        'Sets the @email part of string
        eMail = "" & "somewhere.com"

        'Sets the amount of characters for the last name
        leftVal = 1
        'sets the unique number to add to the end if the username exist increment it
        addUniqueNo = 1

        'sets up the username
        uName = fName + Left(lName & addUniqueNo, leftVal) + "@" + eMail

        'sets up the check username
        preUname = uName

        'Until the username is unique
        Do While UCase(uName) = UCase(preUname)

            'Sets the username (including the unique number if required)
            uName = fName + Left(lName & addUniqueNo, leftVal) + "@" + eMail

            'Checks if the username already exists
            With Worksheets(1).Range("C:C")
                Set c = .Find(uName, LookIn:=xlValues)
                'If username doesnt exist change comparison string to not match
                If c Is Nothing Then
                    preUname = ""
                Else 'If username does exist update the preUname to match (to ensure it loops again)
                    preUname = uName
                End If
            End With

            'Adds each character to the end until there are no more then adds a number starting at 1
            If leftVal > (Len(lName) + 1) Then
                addUniqueNo = addUniqueNo + 1
            Else
                leftVal = leftVal + 1
            End If


        Loop

        'Outputs the username
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNumber, 3) = uName


    Next rowNumber

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @ClintB. It works exactly the way i intended. Thanks again for your help. You saved my day.  :) :) :)